# Is there any way to get only unique matches with preg_match_all?

Tags: php, regex

Hello I want to get all the unique matches of the following. How can I do it?

```
preg_match_all('#http://[\S]+(?:jpe?g|png|gif)#is', $content, $filtered);

$filtered = array_unique($filtered[0]);
foreach($filtered as $value){
${'varpics' . $i} .= '<img width="200px" height="200px" src="'.$value.'"><br>'; }
```

I still get double matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Just pass the results through [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

Unless you wanted to get real fancy with [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and push the matches into a set.

---

```
<?php
$content = <<<HTML
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/image1.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/image2.gif" />
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/image1.jpg" />
HTML;

preg_match_all('#http://[\S]+(?:jpe?g|png|gif)#is', $content, $matches);
$images = array_unique($matches[0]);

var_dump($images);
```

Works perfectly for me. Output:

```
array
  0 => string 'http://www.mysite.com/image1.jpg' (length=32)
  1 => string 'http://www.mysite.com/image2.gif' (length=32)
```

You've got a lot of other things wrong with your code though. For example, where is `$i` defined? And why are you trying to define variables like that? Use an array, rather than a name appended with a number... I'm not even sure if that's valid syntax.

Comment: Hi there Mark. Can you please check my updated code ? I still get double results